# Do commercial products exist for lab-scale thyristor triggering?

Tags: pulse, gate-driving, thyristor, scr

Hello fellow stack exchange members!

We're excited about our novel high-voltage voltage-source-converter design that utilizes SCRs/thyristors and commutation circuits. We're now looking to build a down-scale prototype and are seeking advice on firing/gate pulse mechanisms.

We have already designed the hardware for the prototype but need help finding components that can handle individual signals to each of the 18 thyristors. We also need to ensure isolation between our expensive CPU-generated logic signals and the gating signals.

We've come across some three-phase gate driving boards, but they don't meet our needs. Do any of you know of components that could help us out? Your suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So, you have a design, except for the hard part?

Comment: If you designed the hardware then why can't you design the triggering? Seems fairly standard to me that you would design the triggering...*especially* for thyristors which can't turn themselves off and are now used in niche applications and therefore often use circuits quite tailored to the exact circuit in which they are being used.

Comment: Please provide a schematic showing the design as it stands now, and specific quantities for voltages, currents, loads, and timing.

Comment: have you considered photothyristors?

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks for the response. We have made many MOSFET/IGBT-based converters, using typical gate driving circuits, but we have never driven thyristors. We are not sure if we can use typical MOSFET drivers. We will use thyristors with much higher ratings than we need, and we don't care about losses. So, would normal MOSFET drivers work in our case? E.g., we can apply a pulse for 1 ms to turn it on, and then remove the pulse? Or is this not feasible for thyristors?

Comment: @Jasen Do lowish voltage photothyristors exist? I thought they were only used for high-voltage applications?

Comment: @Mattman944  I guess so 

Comment: For smaller SCRs, an opto-SCR or opto-triac can fire the SCR directly, see figs 7-9 https://www.onsemi.cn/pdf/datasheet/moc3072m-d.pdf . For large SCRs you may need some power from a transformer, see my father's expired patent 4048520, sheet 3 https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/c7/ec/83/133afe70fbad7d/US4048520.pdf